# Xslt group parent/child

Tags: xml, xslt, parent

I have a trouble getting the following result from a xml/xslt transformation:

```
<root>
  <node>   
    <id>1</id>
    <parentid></parentid>
    <name>file 1</name>
  <node>
  <node>   
    <id>2</id>
    <parentid></parentid>
    <name>file 2</name>
  <node>
  <node>   
    <id>3</id>
    <parentid>2</parentid>
    <name>file 3</name>
  <node>
  <node>   
    <id>4</id>
    <parentid></parentid>
    <name>file 4</name>
  <node>
  <node>   
    <id>5</id>
    <parentid>2</parentid>
    <name>file 5</name>
  <node>
</root>
```

i would like the output html to be something like:

```
 <ul>
    <li>file 1</li>
    <li>file 2</li>
       <ul>
          <li>file 3</li>
          <li>file 5</li>
       </ul>
    <li>file 4</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node[string-length(parentid)=0]" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </li>
        <xsl:variable name="children" select="parent::*/node[parentid=current()/id]" />
        <xsl:if test="$children">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$children" />
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Using an `<xsl:key>` has a performance advantage, which, of course, doesn't matter at all for small input. To me at least, it also has a clarity advantage, being more declarative, less procedural - but that might be a matter of personal taste.

Comment: True the key has a better performance for larger input, but it requires the understanding of how xsl keys work, which is not required to understand the basic working of this transformation. The Op is obvisouly a XSLT newbie, so I tried to keep it as straightforward as possible. Conceptually the two solutions are pretty much identical, neither is "procedural" (using `for-each` and `call-template` would have been procedural).

Comment: @Alejandro, so how would you call the programming *style* when explicity using constructs with `for-each` and `call-template`?

Comment: @Lucero: Well, it depends. Regarding style there is a classification between *push* and *pull* style. I don't like *brick* templates (a document root rule doing all the transformation), but there is nothing conceptually wrong about using `xsl:for-each` and `xsl:call-template` instructions.

Comment: @Alejandro, Wikipedia has the following definition for "declarative programming": "Declarative programming is often defined as any style of programming that is not imperative. [...] A program that describes what computation should be performed and not how to compute it" - and that's exactly my point. While XSLT is a declarative language, you can still use an imperative style by using constructs which define the *what* instead of the *how*.

Comment: Tnx guys, upgraded my xslt skills with a little more knowledge

Answer (score 2):

The key (no pun intended) is to use an `<xsl:key>` to set up the parent-child relationship. Once that is defined, the rest is easy.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="getchildren" match="node" use="parentid"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates
              select="node[parentid[not(normalize-space())]]"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="name"/></li>
        <xsl:variable name="children" select="key( 'getchildren', id )"/>
        <xsl:if test="$children">
            <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="$children"/></ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```